# 正規表現に合致した特定の文字のみを置換したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

文字列を特定の条件に当てはまった場合のみ置換したいのですが、うまく出来ず困っております。

文字列の例
a1 = "Extension=1200,Type=567,Port=S123,Name=**Suzuki, Taro**,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="
b1 = "Extension=3089,Type=123,Port=S432,Name=**OPS_Temp**,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="

置換条件
[Name]から[,Coverage_Path_1]まで「,」がある場合は「,」から「_」に変換したい

例
条件合致：置換
a1= "Extension=1200,Type=567,Port=S123,Name=Suzuki_Taro,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="
条件合致しない：置換しないでそのまま出力
b1 = "Extension=3089,Type=123,Port=S432,Name=OPS_Temp,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="

試したこと
正規表現で条件の判別をできるところまで完成（？）
置換する処理でどうすればよいの？というところでつまずいてしまっております。

pattern =r"\w*,+\s\w*"

for l in (a1, b1):
if re.search(pattern, l):
print(re.findall(pattern, l))

初歩的な質問ばかりで申し訳ございません。（そもそも方向性が間違っていたらご指摘頂けると幸いです）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

a1 = "Extension=1200,Type=567,Port=S123,Name=Suzuki, Taro,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="
b1 = "Extension=3089,Type=123,Port=S432,Name=OPS_Temp,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2="

print(re.sub(r'(Name.*?)(,+\s)(.*?,Coverage_Path_1)', r'\1_\3', a1))
print(re.sub(r'(Name.*?)(,+\s)(.*?,Coverage_Path_1)', r'\1_\3', b1))

#
Extension=1200,Type=567,Port=S123,Name=Suzuki_Taro,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2=
Extension=3089,Type=123,Port=S432,Name=OPS_Temp,Coverage_Path_1=,Coverage_Path_2=
```

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございました！確認出来ました。